# What is the target demographic of Yuki Yuna is a Hero?

Tags: yuki-yuna-is-a-hero

If you watch just the first episodes, it is a ordinary Mahou Shoujo for tween girls anime...

But the plot thickens into something too heavy for young girls to digest (imo) soon enough.

> The whole dismemberment and viewing themselves as living sacrifices for their god, not to mention the sisterly guilt trip.

With that in mind, where does it fall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The light novel *Washio Sumi wa Yūsha de Aru*, which is set in the same universe 2 years prior and is the prequel of the anime, targets the *seinen* demographic. The *seinen* demographic includes males from 17 years of age and above. It can be safe to assume that the anime *Yūki Yūna wa Yūsha de Aru* is for the same demographic as the light novel.

The show is also broadcast at late night on the primary channel MBS and other channels, at as early as 22:00 and as late as 03:00 late night. The late night showing of the anime implies that it is at least for young adults and not for tween girls as the introduction might have suggests.

Sources:

- [Wikipedia - Yūki Yūna wa Yūsha de Aru](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y%C5%ABki_Y%C5%ABna_wa_Y%C5%ABsha_de_Aru): *Washio Sumi wa Yūsha de Aru*'s target demographic
- Seinen definition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seinen_manga
- TV schedule: http://live.nicovideo.jp/watch/lv195090725

Comment: Late night anime can still be shounen or shoujo demographic, though that isn't the case here. For instance, Akatsuki no Yona (currently airing) is more shoujo than josei, but airs in late night slots. I think it's expected that many of the viewers (including the youngest ones) will record it rather than watch at airtime, so the airtime doesn't say that much about the target demographic.

Comment: @LoganM: I think late night anime are in general not fit for young viewers (primary school) - they are at least aimed at slightly more mature (around middle school and up). Even a relatively tamed one like Akatsuki no Yona has betrayal and depiction of people being killed with real weapon, so I doubt parents would allow their children to watch them. Regarding **target** demographic of Yuyuyu, I'd guess it would draw in male viewers, since all characters are female (but the actual demographic might not be so skewed, as demonstrated by Madoka, which enjoys viewership from both sexes).

Comment: I showed the ep 8 and 9 to my wife, she was all " gross, no way!" with the whole sacrifice thing. If it hit me as a male and caused that reaction, I think you are right on the money.

Comment: @nhahtdh the emphasis on Togo's chest is also a good clue for the male target.